# How to give onPressed a method in custom button flutter

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter

i have custom button and i want to add method in my onpressed from my parameter,unfortunately i'm still stuck what type should i use in my custom button parameter, curently i hard code the onpressed method and pass a string route to navigate the problem is not all my button is made to navigate there is one button to logout, i already used void in my parameter but it's still doesn't work. 
here is my custom button

```
FlatButton buttonMenu(String title, IconData icon, String route) {
    return new FlatButton(
      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
      child: new Container(
        height: 50.0,
        width: 120.0,
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
              child: new Icon(
                icon,
                color: Colors.white70,
                size: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
            new Text(
              title,
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/$route');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and here is how i call the custom button

```
 buttonMenu('MVP Arc', Icons.star, 'EmployeeScreen')
```

and what i want is i can send method in my parameter to my onpressed so it will be like this

```
buttonMenu('MVP Arc', Icons.star, myMethod())
```

my method for navigate

```
void _navigate(String route){
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/$route');
  }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the `onPressed` type is `VoidCallback` so make your parameter like this this type.

```
FlatButton buttonMenu(String title, IconData icon, VoidCallback onCustomButtonPressed )
```

and when you call it pass a reference to it

```
buttonMenu('MVP Arc', Icons.star, myMethod)
```

and don't forget to do the same in your function body

```
  onPressed: onCustomButtonPressed ,
```

**UPDATE:**
if you want to pass parameters you have to declare your own Signature :

> Example in your case :

```
typedef VoidNavigate = void  Function(String route);
```

and then use this new type

```
FlatButton buttonMenu(String title, IconData icon, VoidNavigate onCustomButtonPressed)
```

call it like this

```
onPressed: (){onCustomButtonPressed},
```

and you pass your function like this

```
buttonMenu('MVP Arc', Icons.star, _navigate('EmployeeScreen'))
```

or you can just do it like this as @Kirill Shashov said

```
buttonMenu('MVP Arc', Icons.star, () {_navigate('EmployeeScreen');})
```

Comment: what should i use in my method it says The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore cannot be used.

Comment: i updated my question and add my method to navigate and my custom button will be like this buttonMenu('MVP Arc', Icons.star, _navigate('EmployeeScreen')) but there is a error says cant be use void

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang try this: `buttonMenu('MVP Arc', Icons.star, () {_navigate('EmployeeScreen');})`

Comment: yep done thanks i use this and work  buttonMenu('MVP Arc', Icons.star, (){ _navigate('EmployeeScreen');})

Comment: sorry for the delay @KirillShashov way is the best for you but i added another way so you can understand better

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me:

Flutter Version : 2.6.0
Dart Version : 2.15.0

in my customButton function:

```
Widget customButton(VoidCallback onPressed) 

{
....
onPressed : onPressed.call(),
}
```

and no other changes needed.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer for passing parameters no longer seems to work on newer versions of Flutter.

In case someone searches for a similar issue, the modifications below worked for me.

> Modifying Raouf Rahiche's answer, the working method as of 2019. October 28 is as follows.
>
> **Update:** *added mising flutter version number below*
>
> Flutter version: 1.9.1+hotfix.5
>
> Dart version: 2.5.0

Using the existing typedef:

```
typedef VoidNavigate = void Function(String route);
```

Using the type changed in a small way, you have to pass the parameter to the button separately.

```
FlatButton buttonMenu(
   String title,
   IconData icon, 
   VoidNavigate onCustomButtonPressed, 
   String route //New addition
) {
   ...
}
```

Calling it now:

```
onPressed: () { onCustomButtonPressed(route); },
```

Passing the function:

```
buttonMenu('MVP Arc', Icons.star, _navigate, 'EmployeeScreen')
```

Comment: Update your answer with the flutter version from which your solution works. (End of Review).

Comment: Thank you ZF007, I forgot to add that, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

the only we need to do is  add .call() to the end of the function to be void.
onPressed: ()=>onPressed   to onPressed: ()=>onPressed.call()